# How to group post by custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, group-by, custom-fields

In wordpress I have a type of post called 'projects' and this post has a custom field called 'year'.

I would like to show all the 'projects', basically their names and description but I would like to show only once the year of execution of it.
Like this

**1991**
project 1
project2
**1995**
project2.1
project 2.2
**1996**
project A2.1
project A2.11
**1997**
project AA

I have made this query

```
<?$wp_query->query('post_type=project_post&posts_per_page=-1&orderby=year&order=ASC');?>
```

But doing this I'll get this result

1991 project 1
1991 project2
1995 project2.1
1995 project 2.2
1996 project A2.1
1997 project AA

Comment: You're not going to be able to do that unless you add a second custom field because of the inconsistent naming scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
'post_type=project_post&posts_per_page=-1&orderby=meta_value_num&meta_key=year'
```

Notice `orderby=meta_value_num&meta_key=year`, so it'll be ordered by custom key and by default it's `ASC`, so no need to mention it.

Read more on [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: Yeah, but how to print the year once?

    <div class="project" >
       <div><?the_field( "year" );?></div>
        <div><?the_title();?> </div>
       
    </div>

Comment: putting this `echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'year', true);`
I retrieve always the year for all post...
what I'm looking is for printing the 'year' field once

Comment: I mean I kind of this

1996 project 1
     project 2
     project 3
1997 project 4
     project 5

Grouped by year field

Comment: I assumed that you are in the loop and using `$post->ID` with `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'year', true)` and if you did it right then it should return the field for this post only. Check [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). BTW, do you have `$post = WP_Query(...)` ?

Comment: it didn't work..thank you so much anyway for your time and help. My purpose is quite difficult. I need to show once the 'year' field when the value of it is repeated. I mean if I have two posts with the same value for 'year' I need to show it only one. Is like kind of grouping posts by the value of field 'year'. Kind of this: 1995 project1 , project2, project3// 1996 project4, project5// 1997 project6// 1998 project7, project8, project9// –

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'   => 'project_post',
    'meta_key'    => 'time',
    'orderby'     => 'meta_value'
) );
$any = '';
while ($the_query->have_posts() ) :
        $the_query->the_post();
        $temp_date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'time', true );?>
    <div class="project" >
    <?if ($temp_date != $any ) {
        $any = $temp_date;?>
    <div><?echo date( "Y", strtotime( $any));?></div>
    <?}else{?><div class="field"></div><?}?>
   <div><?the_title();?> </div>
   <div><?the_field( "region" );?></div>
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>

<?endwhile;?>
```